# Faulty memory or controller?

Tags: memory, dell, dell-poweredge

I have a issue on a Dell PowerEdge R420 on CentOS 6, with 6 * 8GB RAM.

I started seeing :

```
Nov  9 16:43:45 hostname kernel: [20343924.149151] sbridge: HANDLING MCE MEMORY ERROR
Nov  9 16:43:45 hostname kernel: [20343924.149156] CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 0 Bank 9: cc00008c000800c1
Nov  9 16:43:45 hostname kernel: [20343924.149160] TSC 0 ADDR 421c11000 MISC 90024f4dae6988c PROCESSOR 0:206d7 TIME 1478727825 SOCKET 0 APIC 0
[...]

Nov  9 16:43:46 hostname kernel: [20343925.090225] EDAC sbridge: Lost 6 memory errors
Nov  9 16:43:46 hostname kernel: [20343925.090369] EDAC MC0: CE row 2, channel 0, label "CPU_SrcID#0_Channel#3_DIMM#0": 2 Unknown error(s): memory scrubbing on FATAL area OVERFLOW: cpu=0 Err=0008:00c1 (ch=1), addr = 0x421c0c000 => socket=0, Channel=3(mask=8), rank=0
Nov  9 16:43:46 hostname kernel: [20343925.090373]
[...] It repeats multiple time for row 0 and 1 as well.
```

This makes me think memory DIMM are not faulty, but rather the controller. The chance that all 3 DIMMs on the same controller are faulty but none on the other one is unlikely.

```
$ edac-util -v
mc0: 0 Uncorrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: 0 Corrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: csrow0: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#0_Channel#1_DIMM#0: 754182 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#0_Channel#2_DIMM#0: 7181 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow2: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow2: CPU_SrcID#0_Channel#3_DIMM#0: 16891 Corrected Errors
mc1: 0 Uncorrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc1: 0 Corrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc1: csrow0: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc1: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#1_Channel#1_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow1: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc1: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#1_Channel#2_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow2: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc1: csrow2: CPU_SrcID#1_Channel#3_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
```

Can anybody confirm the issue ? What can I do ?
If this is really the DIMM that are dying, how can I know which it is ?

```
*-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 1000
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 48GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: 36KSF1G72PZ-1G4M1
         vendor: 002C04B3002C
         physical id: 0
         serial: 3067A18C
         slot: DIMM_A1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: 36KSF1G72PZ-1G4M1
         vendor: 002C04B3002C
         physical id: 1
         serial: 30679E65
         slot: DIMM_A2
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: 36KSF1G72PZ-1G4M1
         vendor: 002C04B3002C
         physical id: 2
         serial: 30679E66
         slot: DIMM_A3
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)

   *-bank:6
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: 36KSF1G72PZ-1G4M1
         vendor: 002C04B3002C
         physical id: 6
         serial: 30679E63
         slot: DIMM_B1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:7
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: 36KSF1G72PZ-1G4M1
         vendor: 002C04B3002C
         physical id: 7
         serial: 30679CF1
         slot: DIMM_B2
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:8
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: 36KSF1G72PZ-1G4M1
         vendor: 002C04B3002C
         physical id: 8
         serial: 30679CEF
         slot: DIMM_B3
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

Comment: Switch all of the DIMMs to opposite slots, and then see where the errors occur.

Comment: I would like to be able to pin-point the DIMM on the motherboard without having to shutdown the server since I have lots of clients relying on it. I'm wondering if mc0 are the first 1 DIMM, and mc1 are the other 3.

Comment: You will have to shut down the server anyway, to replace the faulty component! Migrate everyone to the other server.

Comment: But I would need 2 maintenance window, 1 to switch all DIMMs, leave the server running to find the issue, shut-it down again to replace the DIMMs.

Comment: Or the motherboard. Either way, that's why you have two servers.

Answer (score -1):

You can blacklist edac then the idrac/bmc will record the slot at the hardware level. The edac module blocks the hardware from recording the issue.
https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln283389/edac-errors-in-messages-log-in-redhat-enterprise-linux-rhel-and-poweredge?lang=en

Comment: Link only answers are not very useful due to link-rot (I've had several answers of mine die that way). Please include enough details in this answer for it to be viable when the link rots.